# Execute a cronjob once a day, when machine is on, but not necessarily at a specific time

Tags: automation, cronjob

I want to run a cronjob once every day on a machine that doesn't run all the time, but runs at least once a day for a couple of hours. The problem with a cronjob is, that I have to give it the exact time, when it is supposed to run, but my machine may not be running at this particular time. I know there is an option to cron that says "do this, when booting" but my machine usually isn't rebooted, but I leave it in standby. 
Put differently, I want to execute something once a day, but I can't give an exact time. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like [anacron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron):

> anacron is a computer program that
>   performs periodic command scheduling
>   which is traditionally done by cron,
>   but without assuming that the system
>   is running continuously. Thus, it can
>   be used to control the execution of
>   daily, weekly, and monthly jobs (or
>   anything with a period of n days) on
>   systems that don't run 24 hours a day.

Available as packages in most Linux distributions. There's probably also a port for MS Windows...

Comment: This is the answer. Perfect

Answer (score 0):

You  could invoke the job from a startup script in /etc/rc2.d which compares today's date with one saved in a file and then updates that file.